# How to fix button position next to input when screen resizes

Tags: html, css, forms

I've been digging around and as im new to css im unsure what i can do to ensure my submit button 'snaps' left to the drop down selector option. At present under different screen sizes the button moves further away. The input and selector appear 'snapped' together im just not sure how i can do this also with the submit button. Originally the button was on the left hand side but i used float:right; to move it to the right. Here is the code for the div:

```
<div class="dm-reg">
<form action="http://detorr.co.uk/hosting/domainchecker.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="direct" value="true" />
Domain: <input type="text" name="domain" /> <select name="text">
<option>.co.uk</option>
<option>.org.uk</option>
<option>.me.uk</option>
<option>.uk</option>
<option>.com</option>
<option>.net</option>
<option>.org</option>
<option>.eu</option>
<option>.biz</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
</div>
```

The css i'm using at present it:

```
.dm-reg input[type=submit]{
position:relative;
color:#ffffff;
background: #3b88d8;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(0% 100% 90deg, #377ad0, #52a8e8);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#52a8e8), to(#377ad0));
border-top: 1px solid #4081af;
border-right: 1px solid #2e69a3;
border-bottom: 1px solid #20559a;
border-left: 1px solid #2e69a3;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #72b9eb, 0 1px 2px 0 #b3b3b3;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #72b9eb, 0 1px 2px 0 #b3b3b3;
border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
float:right;
width:50px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family: arial;
}
```

If possible i would like to know the best way to keep the submit button next to the other input fields regardless of size. I will update my mobile and tablet templates separately.

Please see this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Dtorr1981/vp0zwxsu/2/

Best Regards
Donna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `float:left` add `float:none; display:inline-block;`

As you have mentioned them to be float:left in input.button == > it appears on left side
&
display:block in input.button == > it appears in another line

Check this jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/vp0zwxsu/3/